# Nodejs typescript: declarer custom data type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have multiple services and all of them return same result:

```
type result = {
  success: boolean
  data?: any
}

const a = async (): Promise<result> => {
  ...
}

const b = async (): Promise<result> => {
  ...
}
```

But data of `a` is different of `b`:

```
const a = async (): Promise<result> => {
  return {
    success: true,
    data: { x: 1 }
  }
}

const b = async (): Promise<result> => {
  return {
    success: true,
    data: { y: 1 }
  }
}
```

And I want to change only data type for each one

```
data: { x: 1 } as anotherTypeX
data: { x: 1 } as anotherTypeY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of generics will solve this issue for you and you will have proper typing support.

See docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```js
type result<T> = {
  success: boolean;
  data?: T;
}

type A = {
   x: number;
}
type B = {
   y: number;
}

const a = async (): Promise<result<A>> => {
  return {
    success: true,
    data: { x: 1 }
  }
}

const b = async (): Promise<result<B>> => {
  return {
    success: true,
    data: { y: 1 }
  }
}
```